# Can you fix the this card I made in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a design of a card that I want to implement in my flutter project. I want the name of the card to be clickable, then the trash icon and pencil can also be clicked.

**Here is my code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/constants/color_constant.dart';

class CardCollection extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardCollection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final double _borderRadius = 24.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_borderRadius),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: const [kLightRedColor, kLightOrange],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: const [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: kDarkGreyColor,
                      blurRadius: 12,
                      offset: Offset(0, 6),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/bag_1.png',
                        height: 64,
                        width: 64,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Name of The Collection',
                            style: TextStyle(color: kWhiteColor, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my color_constants.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF1B383A);
const kSecondaryColor = Color(0xFF59706F);
const kDarkGreyColor = Color(0xFFA8A8A8);
const kWhiteColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
const kZambeziColor = Color(0xFF5B5B5B);
const kBlackColor = Color(0xFF272726);
const kTextFieldColor = Color(0xFF979797);
const kVeryDarkCyan = Color.fromRGBO(7, 34, 39, 1);
const kDarkModerateCyan = Color.fromRGBO(53, 133, 139, 1);
const kModerateCyan = Color.fromRGBO(79, 189, 186, 1);
const kPowderBlue = Color.fromRGBO(176, 224, 230, 1);
const kDarkBlue = Color.fromRGBO(34, 87, 122, 1);
const kPurple = Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 38, 102);
const kModerateCyanLimeGreen = Color.fromRGBO(87, 204, 153, 1);
const kSoftLimeGreen = Color.fromRGBO(128, 237, 153, 1);
const kRedColor = Color.fromRGBO(218, 18, 18, 1);
const kLightRedColor = Color.fromRGBO(255, 99, 99, 1);
const kLightOrange = Color.fromRGBO(255, 173, 96, 1);
const kGreenColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 32, 170, 110);
```

here is my skecth(sorry if its bad)
[image]

Let me know if you need more source code, thank you for reading my question(or my request).

Comment: How about using `ListTile`?

Comment: You want to this type of design?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh maybe later when I get used to other flutter widgets

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes, for training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you. if you want design as above image.

```
  Container(
        height: 130,
        width: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          border: Border.all(),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  width: 60.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[50],
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/1.png',
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text(
                    'Put Your Title Here',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('Delete Button Pressed');
                    //write onpressed function here
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('Edit Button Pressed');
                    //write onpressed function here
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want any widget to be clickable, you can wrap it in a `Inkwell` widget and set the `onTap` property.

Comment: okay let me try

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
                Row(
                  children: [
                    // replace placeholder with your image widget
                    Placeholder(
                      fallbackHeight: 40,
                      fallbackWidth: 80,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {}, // provide your click function
                          child: Text('Title'),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {}, // provide your click function
                              icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {}, // provide your click function
                              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: thanks, I am going to try to implement your code.